# If I don't want to teach, is there any advantage to getting my CFI/CFII?

Tags: pilot-certification, cfi

The title pretty much says it all. I'm not a good teacher, and I don't have any interest in instructing students. So, if I'm not going to get a job at a flight school, would getting a CFI certificate actually benefit me?

Just for context, I'm a "weekend warrior" that just flies family and friends around because it's fun (although, given just how much fun I'm having, a career change isn't out of the question).

Comment: The experience would not NOT benefit you... But what is your long term goal?  It might help as a resume bullet, but then you would have to explain why you have zero instructional hours.  If you are comfortable answering that and have the cash and motivation I say go for it.  You will mostly get opinions here though I think.

Comment: Agree that this is pretty close to opinion-based, although there may be some objective answers to be had.  What is your goal: fly to the $200 hamburger on weekends? Job with XXX?  Something else?  Depending on where you want to end up, that may affect the value of the resume bullet (and/or the possible liability of being a CFI but never having instructed).  If you can edit that into your question, that may help you get answers more specific to "advantage" in your particular path.

Comment: I put some additional context into the question.

Comment: If you have a skill that is lacking (according to you yours is teaching) would it be worth it to try instruction in order to round out your skill sets? Would you be teaching others (even informally) in your commercial aviation pursuits?

Answer (score 7):

The big advantage of getting a CFI/CFII for the instructor is it will make them a better more well-rounded pilot.

The material that is covered in the CFI/CFII course was already taught to you in the instrument and commercial phases of  your training.

The old adage goes... things that are taught may be remembered... if you can teach it to someone else then you have really learned the material. (or something similar to this).

You may be able to fly within standards using your techniques and procedures that work for you.  Those may not work for a different pilot and learning and being able to adapt your techniques and procedures to fit another pilot is eseential from a great instructor.

When you get a job flying SIC in a turbojet, you will learn many new things and their techniques and procedures will be different than yours.  If you have exposed yourself to as many different techniques and procedures before you get that job, the transition will be easier.

Even if you don't teach (I highly recommend it to make you a better pilot), learning the commercial and instrument theory from an instructional teaching standpoint will force you to learn the material better and make you a better pilot.

Answer (score 4):

Some other things Ive seen CFI's do that is not out right teaching flight students:

- [BFR's.](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/61.56) and IPC's Everyone needs em...
- My flight club requires a checkout with a club instructor all of whom are members to be able to fly the club planes. I sometimes fly with an instructor just to brush up on things I have not done in a while. While the later is not any "new" instruction it may involve some "teaching"